# Change the height of v-list-item in v-list-item-group

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<v-list dense v-if="groups">
 <v-list-item-group v-model="id" color="primary" mandatory>
    <v-list-item v-for="item in groups" :key="item.ID">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.Name"></v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>
```

How can I change the height of a list item?
Based on what I see when inspecting the html elements I have tried things like:

```
.v-list-item--link.theme--light {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
}

.v-list-item__content {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should get the whole item container: `.v-list-item`, and some attribute like `dense`  have also effect on the height, so you might add `!important` to override it.

Answer (score -1):

although this post is old, I hope it still helps you, as I recently needed to set the maximum list size.

```
<v-list class="max-v-list-height" ...>
```

```
<style scoped>
...
>>> .max-v-list-height {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
...
</style>
```